# Hibernate Search on OneToMany field doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate-search

These are my Place and Category classes:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "placeAnalyzer", ...)
public class Place
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition = "placeAnalyzer")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "place", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Set<Category> categories;

    ...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Category
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    @Field
    @Analyzer(definition="placeAnalyzer")
    private String name;

    @ContainedIn
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="place_id")
    private Place place;
}
```

This is how I create Query:

```
Query searchStringQuery = queryBuilder.keyword()
                    .onFields("name", "location.city", "location.address", "categories.name")
                    .matching(TextUtils.stripAccents(searchString))
                    .createQuery();
```

However search doesn't return results, when I search for some text, which is contained in category table name field. It workds for other fields used in the query. What is wrong here?

Comment: Looks ok so far. Your code does not show the 'location' property, but I guess you just omitted it. Can you give some test data? Are you sure there should be a hit? You could try Luke to inspect the index to verify that the Category fields got indexed. Also, check the logs whether there is something unusual.

Comment: Can you post your code for placeAnalyzer? The first thing that comes to mind, if there absolutely should be hits, is that you're removing accents when searching, but I don't see anywhere that you're removing them when indexing, unless it's in placeAnalyzer.

Comment: From @AndrewRobie 's "answer" (which should be a comment and is likely to get removed): can you post your code for `placeAnalyzer`? The first thing that comes to mind, if there absolutely should be hits, is that you're removing accents when searching, but I don't see anywhere that you're removing them when indexing, unless it's in `placeAnalyzer`.